# Gerrit push to refs/for/master prohibited

Tags: git, push, gerrit

I have updated the *All Project* access permission yesterday, people says that they cannot push changes to repository this morning. After I recovered the access permission, they still cannot push changes to repository, only `clone` works fine. While push changes to remote repository, it says that:

```
![remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (prohibited by Gerrit)
```

All our other projects are inherit from *All project*'s access permission, I updated the access permission to the lowest level (i.e. *Anonymous* can push branch to `refs/heads/*`) for test, but I find that the *Administrator* cannot push changes to the repository too!

Is there any other settings need to add?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To push to the review branches (i. e. `refs/for/*`), you have to set the permission "Push" for the reference `refs/for/refs/*`. You then also need the permission `Label Code Review`, `Label verified` and `Submit` for the reference `refs/heads/*` to do the actual code review.

If you don't want code review, but push directly to the branch, then your permissions are correct, but then you also have  to push to `refs/heads/master`, and not `refs/for/master`.

Comment: Actually, I have set the '''Read Access''' to permission +1, and this permission only allow group members to clone/pull repository but not allow them to upload their modifications. Once I set this to permission +2, the group members can upload their changes now.

Comment: Do you use Gerrit 2.1.x or older? My description is for Gerrit 2.2.x and newer, in that versions the permission scheme has changed.

Comment: Mybe, I always using the newest release software :)

Answer (score 0):

adding following line in Git config file worked for me:

**push=HEAD:refs/for/master**