# Submitting refs/drafts rejected by gerrit . But able to upload 'changes'

Tags: git, gerrit

I am trying to submit a draft change to our gerrit .But it fails with the following error.
However , I am able to submit 'changes' ( patch sets ) successfully.

```
            <~/build> git push origin HEAD:refs/drafts/remote-branch
            Counting objects: 16, done.
            Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
            Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
            Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 5.98 KiB, done.
            Total 13 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
            remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/3)
            To ssh://<my-repo>
            ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/drafts/remote-branch (prohibited by Gerrit)
            error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<my-repo>'

            <~/build> git push origin HEAD:refs/for/remote-branch
            Counting objects: 16, done.
            Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
            Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
            Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 5.98 KiB, done.
            Total 13 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
            remote: Resolving deltas:   0% (0/3)
            To ssh://<my-repo>
            * [new branch]      HEAD -> refs/for/remote-branch
            <~/build>
```

Is there any option we need to configure to enable 'drafts' in Gerrit or configuring some user permissions ?

Comment: you need push permissions on refs/drafts/* more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8483692/1342413